# DOSBox on Windows 10- How to mount a network location?

Tags: dosbox

I am trying to use DOSBox to mount a folder on a different machine, both running Windows 10.

I've tried mounting `//PC-NAME/filename` as it displays in Windows Explorer, but it doesn't work.

Mounting shortcuts doesn't work either. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! You can't mount the first directory. You have to use a subdirectory:

`//PC-NAME/filename/subdirectory`

Answer (score 5):

On the console there exists the command `net use` for such cases.
In DOSbox the `mount` command is used instead. Examples:

`mount c c:\temp`

`mount n //Snoopy/temp/`

For network shares seems it is critical to have that additional `/` at the end. These mount commands can be also placed in your `dosbox-0.74.conf` file located in `C:\Users\<UserId>\AppData\Local\DOSBox` and you'll have `C:` and `N:` drives available from the start.

This works for me running DOSbox 0.74 on Win7 64-bit.